# Texturing and baking without nodes

Tags: texturing, materials, texture-painting

Why do nodes exist? And how to texture without them?

Is there any python add-on that I can install to get rid of nodes and just hand paint or use any other method? Or do I have to code it myself?

Comment: If you really cannot bear to work with nodes in the simplest set up of inputting an image texture node into the color input of a principled shader to paint on, there is always vertex painting provided you have enough geometry to support the level of detail you want from the painting there. Using the Principled shader has simplified my painting set up time for getting the most out of my texture painting, and I seldom ever use and external painter anymore at all since 3d view painting is better feedback for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to use nodes. You can setup a material in the material properties without ever entering in the node editor. For simple PBR setups it's easily doable.

Click on the colored dot on the left of the field, and choose "Image Texture" and select your image.

[image]

Comment: That is, in fact, _using_ nodes.  A shader node, a material output node, and an image node.  It's why my third sentence says "even it requires a node set-up".

Comment: I don't really agree with your sentence because you're saying that two different layers of abstraction are the same thing, when in fact they're both layers of abstraction from dynamically generated shaders. It's a bit like saying you're using nodes when you are in the Texture Properties panel, when in fact you are not, but internally they're kind of doing the same thing. But it's a matter of point of view, and our OP seems to really have an aversion for nodes so I guess it's a good compromise. This is just one layer of abstraction higher than nodes. I didn't DV your answer btw.

Comment: I didn't think you DVed my answer.  It's not something I'd have ever thought you would do. I also think your answer was more helpful in so far as it spelled out the technique where I only pointed it out in the manual. But it's not two different layers of abstraction.  It's two different interfaces to the same abstraction.  When you click on the dot and choose something you're editing the node group; just as if you had edited it in the shader editor.  In fact if you open the shader editor you'll see the nodes and if you change the nodes in the editor they'll change in the display.

Comment: If you changed your first sentence to something like "You don't have to edit the node groups directly. You can use the following interface" I think it would be clearer for the OP, and they won't be as surprised down the road when they find out they were editing node groups.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

The simplest painting set up is like this - no "learning nodes" needed, just plug your image texture into the default Principled BSDF shader and paint on it. Save the image in the Image Editor to disk and open it back up with your favorite external painter software and carry on with the fun part, and you can save it and reload in Blender to preview the work again. Once you get comfortable, you can stretch out and experiment with what happens when you adjust the sliders or plug separate images into the inputs on the Principled node...

Answer (score 2):

Shader nodes exist because that is how you describe materials to Blender so it knows what colors to use.  They're simple enough to use, and Blender has already added nodes for geometry and it working on nodes for animation, so they're becoming prevalent.

There is not an add-on that would do away with nodes; although there are a few that are designed to make it easier to use nodes.

There is a technique to hand paint materials onto an object, [*texture painting*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/texture_paint/introduction.html) but even it requires a node set-up.

Comment: Is it feasible to just extract the uv map and color it in gimp or do I have to spend another 20 hours in front of tutorials just to learn how to use those damn nodes? Learning new stuff  is cool and all..but why make systems that do nothing but slow down and make things harder?

Comment: You can use Texture painting, which is what I mentioned and the answer you accepted describes.  It's easier to learn but in the long run will be harder and slower to use.  Learning to use the material nodes is slow; but once learned using them is fast.

Comment: To answer your question.  There's an add-on to export UV Maps, You have to enable it in Preferences. You export the UV Map as an image. You can use the exported map as a layer in Gimp to guide your painting.

Comment: @RPG life  You can go to the UV editor-image-edit externally, and this will open an image editing program you set in your preferences under file paths- image editor.

Comment: @MartyFouts are nodes usable in game engines or do they just work in blender?

Comment: Game engines that use nodes have different nodes than Blender, except, of course, BGE. Exporters that export data from Blender and importers that read the data into the game engine might try to translate Blender's node-based materials into a format the game engine understands.  They have varying degrees of success with this.